# How to create dynamic element with iterative class name?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to create tab dynamically with iterative for each as bellow, but its creating space like `tab-btn 1`, `tab-btn 2`. How to iterate for class name.

```
<li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active tab-btn1">View Document - 01</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab-btn2">View Document - 02</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab-btn3">View Document - 03</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab-btn4">View Document - 04</a>
                </li>
```

I have created for loop as bellow,

```
  @{int i = 0;}
            @foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab-btn @i">@item["M36_01_TypeName"]</a>
                </li>
                i++;
            }
```

I have also tried as suggest in excepted answer of [Razor - using foreach, insert html every nth item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013161/razor-using-foreach-insert-html-every-nth-item) but its also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `string.Format()`

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class=@string.Format("tab-btn{0}", i)>@item["M36_01_TypeName"]</a>
```